# No Inbound Nodes - Keras CNN Model

Tags: python, keras-layer

I had trained a CNN model in keras with the following structure

```
model_11 = Sequential()

#Convolutional Layers
model_11.add(Reshape((55, 1)))
model_11.add(Conv1D(50, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding="same", activation = 'relu'))
model_11.add(Conv1D(24, kernel_size=4, strides=5, padding="same", activation = 'relu'))
model_11.add(Conv1D(23, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding="same", activation = 'relu'))

#Dense Layers
model_11.add(Flatten())
model_11.add(Dense(units=30, activation='relu'))
model_11.add(Dense(units=15, activation='relu'))

model_11.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

#Compile model
model_11.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Fit the model
model_11.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=20)
```

Now, I tried the following

```
model_11.layers[-3].output
```

Which gives me the following error

> AttributeError: Layer dense_40 has no inbound nodes.

There are many solutions regarding multiple inbound nodes, but I haven't seen anything so far for no inbound nodes. And despite that, the model is working well (binary classification).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you define a `Sequential` without specifying the input shape for the first layer, the computation graph is only created during the `fit` function, and thus layers' input and output tensors (and thus nodes) are not computed.

If you need to access output tensor of a layer, specify the input shape for the first layer in the sequential model. Thus the first layer is defined as this:

```
model_11.add(Reshape((55, 1), input_shape=(55,))
```

Now `model_11.layers[-3].output` will return a tensor.